# DevOps deployment based on releases

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory instance which is linked to github, used for development.

I am having two different changes in the two different branches of data factory.
**change01** and **change02**

I have merged these two changes into **master** branch and did a publish.

While doing a CI/CD even though these two changes are now available in the dev data factory instance, is it possible to deploy only change01 into other environments?

How can we control which release/change should go for deployment into other environments?
Can we do a build directly from a branch and push to prod?

Comment: Please provide feedback if any of the answers were helpful/need to be refined further.

Answer (score 1):

To best accomplish this will have to to publish outside of the Data Factory editor.  Each branch contains the necessary ARM components to publish the Data Factory ARM templates.  The issue is when clicking the publish button Data Factory/ADO behind the scenes consolidates the ARM templates to just one .json file to make it easier to deploy while simultaneously deploying to the Data Factory destination.

The best course of action here might be to determine how to publish the ARM templates w/o clicking the publish button.  This can be done by using ARM deployments or Powershell.

Furthermore I'd consider the [potential options](https://blog.johnfolberth.com/understanding-data-factory-in-a-ci-cd-world/) you have when considering how to managed and deploy Data Factory under CI/CD.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use separate branch and configure your builds to use proper one. Verify you builds in Azure Dev Ops.

It can be also helpful to cherry-pick changes which shouldn't be deployed.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with how Data Factory Git configuration is configured.